# Basic equinumerous examples

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $a < b$ are real numbers, then

1. $(a,b) \sim (0,1)$
2. $[a,b] \sim (0,1)$

---

For the first one, it is quite simple.

Pf (1): Let $f:(a,b)\rightarrow (0,1)$ be defined by $f(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$. Clearly, $f$ is a bijection.

Pf(2): Let $g:[a,b]\rightarrow (0,1)$... (here I want to say something along the lines of) be defined by $g(x)=\frac{x-a}{2(b-a)}, a<x<b$ which clears space for a and b as they are included.. Is this reasoning correct? How do I formally write up the a and b part? Looking for an explanation.

Comment: The answers given there constitute bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1)$. This is similar, but not the same. Only one point is lost there. My answer treats $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ and looses 2wo endpoints simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

2. You have $g(a)=0$ so this is not correct. Any bijection between $[a,b]$ and $(0,1)$ is necessarily not continuous since a continuous image of a compact interval is a compact set. So, we should "loose two points" $0$ and $1$ (I restrict myself to $[0,1]\sim(0,1)$). Put $f(0)=\frac{1}{10}$, $f\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)=\frac{1}{11}$, $f\left(\frac{1}{11}\right)=\frac{1}{12}$ and so on. Similarly, put $f(1)=1-\frac{1}{10}$, $f\left(1-\frac{1}{10}\right)=1-\frac{1}{11}$, $f\left(1-\frac{1}{11}\right)=1-\frac{1}{12}$ and so on. For the remaining $x$ put $f(x)=x$. This construction should lead to the bijection $f\colon[0,1]\to(0,1)$.

In the general case of $[a,b]$ you easily find the affine bijection between $h:[a,b]\to [0,1]$ and take $g=h\circ f.$

Comment: This is more of an analysis way of doing things.. I'm looking to define a function that covers all cases without listing them out..

Comment: Maybe can I consider the function $g(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}*\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: This is an increasing function with $g(b)=\frac{1}{4}$, so $g(x)\le\frac{1}{4}$.  Wrong way. As I have told before, the bijection between $[a,b]$ and $(0,1)$ must be discontinuous but you persistently stick to continuous functions.

Comment: @sgerbhctim: As the author of this answer said, such a bijection can **NOT** possibly be achieved with a continuous function.

Comment: First of all, $g(b) \neq \frac{1}{4}$ in the function I defined. I see what you are saying now, because it must be discontinuous for me to take care of the $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ cases. What if I made a piece wise function, where $g(x)$ holds from $a<x<b$ and then $g(a)=\frac{1}{9}$ and $g(b)=\frac{8}{9}$?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, $g(b)=\frac{3}{4}$ but it still proves that your method is wrong.

Comment: Let me know if my above comment makes sense

Comment: I tell you good night - 1:26 a.m. in Poland. :)

Comment: Does that mean it is correct? Haha.